# List as key in dictionary

Tags: python

I know, i can't put list as key in dictionary in Python.
I need array of strings, and for each string I need to have some values, that I can access through that string.
E.g

```
["string1" : ["string1.1","string1.2","string1.3"], "string2" :["string2.1","string2.2"]]
```

And i need to iterate through strings(string1, string2) and for example print second sub_string(stringX.2) so I get

```
>>"string1.2","string2.2"
```

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: Don't you just want a dictionary `{'string1': ['string1.1', ...], ...}`? A list can't be a key, but it can be a value.

Comment: isn't it better to use a 2d array?

Comment: You can use tuples as dictionary keys, but you don't seem to need them anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dict:

```
dictvalue = {"string1" : ["string1.1","string1.2","string1.3"], 
             "string2" : ["string2.1","string2.2"]}
```

You can iterate over the keys with:

```
for key in dictvalue:
    print dictvalue[key][1:2]
```

Or just iterate over the values directly, since you seem only interested in the values without the keys.

```
for value in dictvalue.values():
    print value[1:2]
```

(Using the `[1:2]` slice notation protects us in case the list has fewer than 2 items it.)

Comment: The OP's example shows values with varying lengths - if the list has fewer than 2 items, `value[1:2]` notation will return an empty list, `value[1]` will raise an IndexError.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your dictionary is:

```
x = {'string2': ['substr2.1', 'substr2.2'], 'string1': ['substr1.1', 'substr1.2', 'substr1.3']}
```

you can use:

```
for key in x:
    print(x[key][1]
```

output would be:

```
substr2.2
substr1.2
```

Comment: If you want to iterate over the keys in a dict, you can just iterate over the dict itself, no need to call `keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the keys ordered use an orderedDict. Then just iterate over the dict items using a try/except to catch and indexError and print the key if you get any error:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict((k,v) for k, v in (("string1", ["string1.1", "string1.2", "string1.3"]), ("string2", ["string2.1", "string2.2"])))

try:
    for k, v in od.items():
        print(k, v[1])
except IndexError as e:
    print("IndexError for key {}".format(k))
```